# Multiple Time zone handling in mvc with multiple users logged in account

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am having MVC application which is hosted in server located in Oregon and it is working in UTC Time zone.

I am using technologies such as Jquery , MVC , C# ,SQL for the application and having UI (Jquery) Inputs such as calendar controls , MVC Date time , SQL and etc.

It is a product and which is having global customers with various time zones. They want to manipulate their data (ie Data date time) in their own time zone format. But Whenever data inserted into DB , It is inserting in UTC Format.

I want to have customized time zone information in their account (Portal).

How can we achieve this?

Simple and great idea is very helpful for me

Example:

1. When User from USA (Ohio) using the system and inserted a record in table by 11 PM their time, but it is showing in application in UTC time, but the user want in their reports with their time 11 PM.
2. When User from USA (Ohio) using the system and inserted a record in table by 
   23rd March 2 AM their time, but System showing inserted in UTC Time with next day. So User thinks and asking why the time difference ?

3.How can I handle Day light saving time in this case?

Thanks

Comment: This is entirely too much for an online forum. All of your questions are valid and are tough challenges. There just isn't a way to write an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function toBrowserTimeZone (value, format) {
    return this.date(new Date(value), format || 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
  }
```

taken as an excerpt from https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat/blob/master/src/dateFormat.js